# Just deploy cloudformation changes with serverless framework for AWS

Tags: serverless-framework

I am making changes just to custom resources in my serverless.yml with an AWS provider.  The package from the lambda code is not changing, it's already uploaded to S3 from a previous deploy.

How can I say "use the artifacts already in S3, just upload the changed cloudformation template and update the stack using that"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Updating only the infrastructure with the Serverless Framework is not something achievable as of right now. You will need to perform a full deployment even if there were no code changes.

However, executing a regular `sls deploy` won't do the trick if no code has changed as the framework won't detect infrastructure changes only. If you want to force a redeployment (i.e you have hooked up a new trigger for your Lambda function in your `serverless.yml` file), you must force the deployment by using the `--force` flag

`sls deploy --force`

Comment: doesn't that upload all artifacts?  I only want the cloudformation artifact uploaded

Comment: It's the only way to update your infrastructure if the code has not changed.

Comment: understood mate.  What I'm looking for is some way for serverless to know that, so it does not re-upload the code.  Its a 25MB jar file in my case, and I'm on a slow connection right now.  My cloudformation file is only a few KB in comparison, and that is what I'm editing.

Comment: I get you now. I wish there was a solution for that already, Many times I had to redeploy the whole code just because I changed an environment variable in the `serverless.yml` file for example. I am afraid that this is not possible as of right now :(

Comment: if you update your answer to say this, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: There it is :).

Comment: I have experienced this issue many times when deploying, I always thought it was a bug, but this makes sense now.